# How can i get document from firebase store?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

This is My data.
I want document by code. 
 So is there any way from which i get the document in flutter?

Comment: What have you tried already? On SO it is recommended that you show what you have attempted already. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Have a look at their documentation for a guide. https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried this way -> i were pulling all the data and then check code one by one with each code of document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get document by code, use a query:

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('classes')
     .where("code", isEqualTo: "9RD2699")
     .getDocuments()
     .then((event) {
       if (event.documents.isNotEmpty) {
         Map<String, dynamic> classDoc = event.documents.single.data;
       }
     }).catchError((e) => print("error fetching data: $e"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get document like that

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getClass({String classId}) async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('classes')
        .doc(classId)
        .get();
  }
```

when you call `getClass(classId: "classId")` you will get document of this class